# How to get JSON array key and value dynamically using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've below JSON, am facing difficulty to get the key and value dynamically from JSON array:

```
var productJSON = {
    "byProduct": {
        "category": {
            "Entertainment": {
                "TV": 7,
                "Speaker": 24,
                "DVD Player": 5,
                "Home Theater": 4
            },
            "Home": {
                "Sofa Couch": 1,
                "TV Furniture": 4
            },
            "Mobile": {
                "iPhone 5s": 1,
                "Accessories": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm want key, value from each category and put in two different array, one for product name and another for product count like:

```
["TV", "Speaker", "DVD Player", "Home Theater","Sofa Couch", "TV Furniture", "iPhone 5s", "Accessories"]

[7, 24, 5, 4,1,4,1,4]
```

Can someone help how can I get the output like this?

How can I get these value from above JSON array, below is my code but not able to parse all the item from each category:

```
var ProductJSON = productJSON.byProduct;
var productsName = [], productCount = [];
Object.keys(ProductJSON.category).forEach(function (v) {
    var k = Object.keys(ProductJSON.category[v])[0];
    productsName.push(k);
    productCount.push(ProductJSON.category[v][k]);
});
console.log(productsName);
console.log(productCount);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You've basically got it. But for some reason you're only grabbing the first products name `Object.keys(ProductJSON.category[v])[0]`. Removing the `[0]` would give you all of the product names.

Comment: But its not giving the count for all Products :(

Comment: You have to iterate over `Object.keys(ProductJSON.category[v])` as well. Or simply use a `for/in` loop: `for (var k in ProductJSON.category[v]) { productsName.push(k);  productCount.push(ProductJSON.category[v][k]); }`.

Comment: Thanks Felix! It worked

Comment: Just a note:  You are dealing with JavaScript `array` and `object` and *not* `JSON`  though they look very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete solution in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pparas/g5a5002g/1/).

```
            var Products = productJSON.byProduct.category;

            var productsName = [], productCount = [];

            for (var product in Products) {
                var items = Products[product]
                for (var item in items) {
                    productsName.push(item);
                    productCount.push(items[item]);
                }
            }
            console.log(productsName);
            console.log(productCount);
```

This is in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using lodash [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach):

```js
var productJSON = {"byProduct": {"category": {"Entertainment": {"TV": 7,"Speaker": 24,"DVD Player": 5,"Home Theater": 4},"Home": {"Sofa Couch": 1,"TV Furniture": 4},"Mobile": {"iPhone 5s": 1,"Accessories": 4}}}};

var Products = productJSON.byProduct.category;
var productsName = [],
    productCount = [];

_.forEach(Products, function(items) {
    _.forEach(items, function(v, k) {
        productsName.push(k);
        productCount.push(v);
    });
});

console.log('productsName: ', productsName);
console.log('productCount: ', productCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```